# Masking IP for outgoing traffic

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline, aws-step-functions

I have created a EC2 instance with ASG and attached a eni . Third party service we invoke  will accept traffic only if it got initiated from the eni IPs.
ASG won’t allow us to assign eni as primary ip . Is there a work around for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a NAT with a static IP so that all outbound connections from your ASG come from the NAT IP rather than the IP of the hosts in the ASG.

See this question https://serverfault.com/questions/625166/static-ip-address-for-outgoing-traffic-from-aws-autoscaling-group